# How do I run more than one sql query (from the psql interactive terminal)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

New to to psql and slightly confused.

I executed the query "select * from users" and got the following result:

[image]

However, I get "END" after I execute the query.

How do I go about executing subsequent queries? (Or exit psql etc.)

Comment: This is absolutely on topic. It's about a programming tool. Read the FAQ. This is a legit question. Leave open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press `q` . It quits the viewer.

Comment: @Sheldon The viewer is actually `less` (usually); it's the "pager" that's set to display long output on your system. To learn more about it type `man less` in a normal command prompt (not within `psql`). You can use any viewer you like by changing the `PAGER` environment var, but most people never need to do that.